# How can directly get the value of a specified cookie name from the header?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In my jsp page i have put

```
${header.cookie}
```

and I got this :

```
JSESSIONID=1bxvxsg61zphc; JSESSIONID=385a85a4ad8a3041ee047d586447; treeForm:tree-hi=treeForm:tree:applications; clientLanguage=fr
```

My question is, how can directly get the value of a specified cookie name without using loop, for example: if i want to get the value of the clientLanguage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

${pageContext.response.locale}

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are available by `${cookie.name}`. So:

```
${cookie.clientLanguage}
```

#### See also:

- [Unified Expression Language - Implicit objects](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

Comment: That is the value from the cookie not from the header.I am not trying to get the value from the cookie, but from header.cookie

Comment: What's the difference for you? Cookies are sent by headers anyway. The `${cookie}` just provides a shortcut to each of the individual cookies. If it didn't work for you, then the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: the value i get from the headers is different from the one i get from the cookie. only in the next reload the values will be the same

Comment: This is a timing problem. You're doing the one before the other (or the other way round). By the way, with `${header.cookie}` you would have exactly the same problem then. Do you anyway understand how cookies work? When you add a cookie to a response, it won't show up in the headers of the *current* request, but of the requests *thereafter*.

Comment: perhaps its a time, problem, but any cant i directly get it from there?

Comment: Why would you? The `${cookie}` is easier and exactly for this purpose.